# R in VS Code prints empty lines to terminal

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, terminal

When I source an R script in VS Code, many empty lines are printed to the terminal.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54650271/5009249) to a similar question, the issue was resolved in 1.37 – but its ilk persists for me in 1.71.2.

What causes these blank, empty lines, and how can I remove them?

Screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Comment: Already tried `source(., echo=TRUE)`?

Comment: @jay.sf I probably said this poorly – my goal is not to have the lines be non-blank but to have the lines not printed at all. Ideally the output would read "[1] Health…" and then immediately on the next line "[1] Food…"

Comment: Does the same problem happen if you use a standard R console rather than a radian console?

Comment: @andycraig I finally looked into this and found, no, the problem does not happen in a standard R console. Any idea what this would mean?

Comment: @Unrelated It looks like it's specific to the radian console rather than R. I'm not sure how to solve it unfortunately. There are many settings for radian so my best suggestion is to try changing the settings one by one and see if any of them make a difference. https://github.com/randy3k/radian#settings